# How to keep the Search Text after reloading the JQGrid Table

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Everytime I load the JQGrid Table I add a 'div' on the top for searching inside the Table(solution already posted in stackoverflow):

```
$('#t_' + $.jgrid.jqID($grid[0].id))
.append($("<div><label for=\"globalSearchText\">Global search in grid for:&nbsp;" +
    "</label><input id=\"globalSearchText\" type=\"text\"></input>&nbsp;" +
    "<button id=\"globalSearch\" type=\"button\">Search</button></div>"));
```

The searching works well. The problem is that if a load the Page the Search Área will get empty. Is there any way to keep the SearchText even after loading the Page?

Comment: you may send search parameter back to client side and set it inside your search fields.

Comment: You have to set the `input` value to match your search query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can use cookies for doing same.

See code below.
<script>

$( document ).ready(function(){

       $("#gs_Customer").blur(function(){
            var searchVal = $("#gs_Customer").val();
            alert(searchVal);
            //here you can set javascript cookies
       });

        $("#gs_Customer").val(searchVal); // Here you can get search text value from cookies. 
}); 
</script>
```